# Connecting Thunderbird to a shared agenda

Tags: thunderbird, gmail, calendar

I'm trying to have my agendas from gmail show up in Thunderbird.

When I login to `calandar.google.com`, I have a number of calendars:

- My agendas

  - my gmail-account
  - contacts
- Other agendas

  - an agenda shared by a friend
  - Holidays in Netherlands

When I follow all the help-files and support articles, I can easily add "my gmail-account" and "contacts". But I cannot connect the agenda shared by a friend, because I do not know the password. I have read-access to this agenda via the google calendar web-interface.

Is there a way to add this friend's calendar to Thunderbird?